# LabVIEW MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, labview

In LabVIEW applicatio, I want to write some data in a `MongoDB`.

I found the `C#` Driver for LabVIEW under the following link: https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-41766

When i open the `LV-project` and try to run an example, i get many errors.

Mainly the class of the driver can´t include / load.

> .NET is installed on the system.

Has someone any idea or can give instructions to get the driver running in LabVIEW?

Comment: What about "Install the mongo-csharp-driver-2.x.x from:" https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/releases ? It the LabVIEW version 2014?

Answer (score 2):

Did you create a LabVIEW.exe.config file (there's an example in the MongoDB-driver package) and store it in the same folder as LabVIEW.exe and relaunch? That did the job for me!

http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/lvhowto/configuring_clr_version/